# sscanf c++ splitting string to ints sometimes doesn't work

Tags: c++, string, split, int, scanf

I am writing a program that converts a date string to three separate int variables: year, month, day.

```
int m,d,y;
sscanf("2011-03-08","%i %*[-] %i %*[-] %i",&y,&m,&d);
cout << y<<" "<<m<<" "<<" "<<d<<std::endl;
sscanf("2011-03-07","%i %*[-] %i %*[-] %i",&y,&m,&d);
cout << y<<" "<<m<<" "<<" "<<d;
```

If I convert 2011-03-08 or 2011-03-09, the day will be 0, but for 2011-03-07,06,... the day is 7,6,... as i would expect. Could somebody explain it, why doesn't it work for 08 or 09 and only for them?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think it may be due to octals, try using %d

Comment: You should really not mix C and C++ this way. These are different languages, so avoid writing C-style code while programming in C++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [`sscanf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html)

> **i**
>   Matches an optionally signed integer; the next pointer must be a pointer to int. The integer is read in base 16 if it begins with 0x or 0X, in base 8 if it begins with 0, and in base 10 otherwise. Only characters that correspond to the base are used.

`08` will be scanned as an octal integer, because it starts with `0`. But `08` is not a valid octal integer, whereas `07` is. If you use `%d` instead of `%i`, it will work as you expect.

```
sscanf("2011-03-08","%d %*[-] %d %*[-] %d", &y, &m, &d);
```

or even simpler

```
sscanf("2011-03-08","%d-%d-%d", &y, &m, &d);
```

---

Depending on what you want to do with the result, you may also consider [`strptime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html)

> strptime  -  convert  a  string  representation  of time to a time tm structure

```
struct tm t;
strptime("2011-03-08, "%Y-%m-%d", &t);
```

Comment: +1. However the guy who asked this question probably should prefer using std::istringstream instead of sscanf.

Comment: @AnotherTest Agreed, this would be the next step. But if he must maintain some existing code, this might not be an option.

Comment: @AnotherTest: streams are not always an option. What if the format is unknown at compilation time ? There are so many date formats around... Furthermore, for more complex parsing tasks, streams just don't hold up to `sscanf` which, in fact, implements a kind of mini-parser. Regular expressions, though, might be more like it; especially now that they are standardized.

Comment: @MatthieuM. That's definitely true. Although if there are only minor differences (eg. if we had a different separator character) in the format which would be only known at runtime, that shouldn't be a problem at all. If you are dealing with more complex languages, you would probably choose a more powerful parsing method anyway. And as you said, regexes are probably a good idea too.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `%i` treats `08` as an octal integer, so possible solution could be to use `%d` instead, **but** since this is C++, you should use [`std::istringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/) (`#include <sstream>`) instead:

```
int y,m,d;
char delimiter;

std::istringstream dateStream("2011-03-08");
dateStream >> y >> delimiter >> m >> delimiter >> d;

std::cout << y << " " << m << " " << d;
```

Comment: You forgot to validate that `delimiter` really is `'-'` each time, which `sscanf` implicitly did for you, so it's not exactly equivalent.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Good point, although I'm not saying it is exactly equivalent to `sscanf`. I just wanted to point out that there are other possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Your format string is wrong... it should simply be `"%4d-%02d-%02d"`

It wouldn't hurt to check that the sscanf worked too with `if (3 != sscanf(...)) { /* failed */ }`